# getJSON returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to make an automatic news feed on a project website, where all the posts are put into a JSON file and then formatted on the news page accordingly. I've finally figured out how to get the json parser to show SOMETHING but that something is just a bunch of "undefined" bits all over the page. What am I doing wrong?

The jquery/html snippet

```
<script>    
    $.getJSON("js/news.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data.posts, function (val) {
                var title = val.title;
                var date = val.date;
                var content = val.content;
                $("#newscontainer").append('<div><h1>' + title + '</h1><h2>' + date +     '</h2><p>' + content + '</p></div>');
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='newscontainer'> 
</div>
```

The JSON snippet

```
{
"posts": [
    {
        "title": "title1",
        "date": "8302014",
        "content": "LotsoftextLotsoftext"
    },
    {
        "title": "title2",
        "date": "8312014",
        "content": "CopiousquantitiesoftextCopiousquantitiesoftext"
    },
    {
        "title": "title3",
        "date": "8322014",
        "content": "onlyalittletext"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` in your code is the `index`, you should use the second argument of the callback.

```
$.each(data.posts, function (index, val) {
```

You can also use the `this` keyword.

Comment: Adding that one little word fixed everything! Thank you so much. I understand why it worked, too... which isn't always the case. I just started coding a few months ago.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

```
var post_title = val.title;
var post_date = val.date;
var post_content = val.content;

var divTag   = document.createElement("div");
newscontainer.appendChild(divTag); 

var h1Tag   = document.createElement("h1");
h1Tag.innerHTML = post_title;
newscontainer.appendChild(h1); 

var h2Tag   = document.createElement("h2");
h2Tag.innerHTML = post_date;
newscontainer.appendChild(h2); 

var pTag   = document.createElement("p");
pTag.innerHTML = post_content;
newscontainer.appendChild(p);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the each() function on your list:

```
    $(data.posts).each(function() {
      var $this = this;
      $("#newscontainer").append('<div><h1>' + $this.title + '</h1><h2>' + $this.date +     '</h2><p>' + $this.content + '</p></div>');
    });
```